# Subclassing numeric types for safety

Tags: java, data-types

I'm writing something that handles length units, say, metres and feet. I don't want to accidentally convert between them (trying to avoid something like the [Mars Climate Orbiter crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure)).

I'd like to use the type system for this, so that the compiler will catch these kind of errors, and only be able to convert between these types very explicitly.

I'm writing this in Java, which I'm not super familiar with. Looks like I can't subclass `Double`.

How should I go about this? I guess I could define my own classes `Metres` and `Feet` but I'd lose the benefits of automatic unboxing. If this was C++ I could add an `operator double` and add arithmetic overloads to make sure I can't operate mixed types, but it looks like I can't do this in Java?

Comment: Why do you want to distinguish between these two units? It seems to me that they both describe the same thing. Therefore, you should most likely have a single class `Distance` which doesn't inherit from another class and has the static methods `fromMeters` and `fromFeet`. Then, you can implement the method `add(Distance otherDistance)` and handle the operation internally.

Comment: Following @VincentSavard's suggestion will also prevent you from accidentally converting kilograms to feet (which might also be stored in a double)

Comment: My immediate reaction to adding operator overloading: what will be the result of adding 10 feet to 1.5 metres?

Comment: [user defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) were added to C++ for this exact purpose

Comment: @GregBurghardt I don't want that to compile. I meant operator overloading in the subtypes, as in adding metres to metres, to avoid having to manually unbox / convert to number / use an ugly `sum` method.

Comment: @esoterik I'm trying to find the least bad way to do something similar in Java :(

Comment: Java does not meet your stated needs: it lacks operator overloading, so your math expressions will be inelegant, it lacks (for now, see https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/06/JavaValuesJun18) user-defined value types, so you will be stuck with the performance impact of boxing. Are you wedded to Java?  If you wish to stay in the JVM family of languages, Scala has a units-of-measure package.  If you want to get out of the JVM world and into the .NET world, F# also has units of measure. A functional language might be a better fit for your problem; what is the business domain of the program?

Comment: See https://github.com/typelevel/squants, https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure/.

Comment: This [Joel on Software](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) post suggests a naming convention to plug the type hole in a similar circumstance, FWIW

Comment: You are suggesting units are types, that your problem would be solved if you had another type that would imply a unit of choice. This is not the case. Your numeric type, whatever it will be, will only give you something that can hold a value. A unit means nothing to a type system, your problem will remain, with any type.

Comment: @Martin "A unit means nothing to a type system": Yes it does when it's part of the type system, as in Scala or F#. It forbids adding apples and oranges at compile time (and also enables more advanced kinds of checks). See also e.g. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ed8a/782dc14300e5a20f080a4406cdddbed38309.pdf

Comment: @GregBurghardt The result will be 4,548e+10 ångström, obviously.

Comment: @JETM thanks for that article. It's interesting that we got Hungarian notation so wrong :) But ideally I'm looking for something with stronger guarantees than that.